# Makefile cannot install code due to previous installation of earlier version

Tags: c++, c, makefile, error-handling

I have previously installed some code using a makefile. Now, I'm installing an updated version of the code (with some added features). The problem is that when I run `make clean; make class` the following error comes up:

```
ld: 13 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [class] Error 1
```

I believe this is because it is trying to install the same files in the same directories as the previous installation. I've tried `make uninstall` on the other installation, but that just returns `` make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop. ``

Is this the reason for the error? If so, do I have to manually uninstall the previously installed files? And how do I do that?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

We need your Makefile for this.
Clean and other commands are defined inside it, make sure that the rules are correctly cleaning the files.

Comment: Hello Jambon, welcome on StackOverflow. As this is not really an answer to the question it is probably better to put it as a comment.